# How do I refute this WTC argument?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

According to the WTC report there were 3000 gallons of jet fuel per tower. So at energy density of 50 MJ/kg and 3 kg/gal that's 50 GJ of energy. The WTC report also says there was 500 tons of steel and concrete per floor with specific heat over 0.5 kJ per kg Kelvin. That means the fire would reach less than 250 Celsius even if it all burned on one floor.

Comment: You got it a little bit off, its 5000 tons per floor, but that just makes WTC look dumber. https://www.nist.gov/engineering-laboratory/final-reports-nist-world-trade-center-disaster-investigation

Comment: Are you assuming all the energy is used to heat the concrete? What about the surrounding air?

Comment: Are you also assuming uniform distribution of fuel & thus heat? I would image the heat being concentrated at particular locations, some of them critical locations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs, if anywhere, on skeptics.SE

Answer (score 5):

Easy.  You go to the house of the person making the claim with a gallon of gasoline.  You pour the gasoline on the garage floor.  You inform the claimant that the garage floor contains approximately 10,000 kg of concrete, and the gallon of gasoline contains approximately 100 MJ of energy, and therefore the temperature will only go up by about 20 degrees C when the gasoline burns.  You hand the claimant a match, and tell him/her to strike it once you're a safe distance away.

Comment: I've never heard the counter-argument worded that way before.  That's beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

1. This assumes even a paper clip worth of steel would still suffice to support the construction. This is blatantly false - only a moderate dent in the structural integrity is enough to make the building collapse.
2. This assumes heat was distributed evenly, fuel heating all parts of the floor at the same rate. No localized zones of much higher temperature, or zones barely affected. Blatantly false, it takes some extremely smart engineering to build furnaces that distribute heat evenly. A building fire is definitely nothing of that kind.
3. Steel doesn't need to melt to lose structural durability - while 250 °C is not enough, even ~800 °C is quite sufficient to compromise the construction.
4. These were offices. While the construction was steel and concrete, there was a plenty of paper, plastic, cloth, and other flammable materials. Jet fuel wasn't the only source of heat.